# including a global variable into a php stylesheet.

Tags: php, css

how can I include a global variable into the style.php file? Basically a php stylesheet.

this is main file:

```
<?php 
function (){
$gbvariable = get_option();

?>

<input type="text" size="20" name="backgroundcolor" value="<?php $gbvariable; ?>"/>

<?php
}
?>
```

this is the style.php file.

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/css');?>

#div{


background: <?php $gbvariable; ?>;

}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Or maybe just start with: http://php.net/manual/en

Comment: `echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/style.php?var1=$gbvariable\" type=\"text/css\" />";` and into style.php file just add `<?php $gbvariable=$_GET['var1']; ?>`

Comment: See also http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54583/how-can-i-use-wordpress-functions-in-my-stylesheet where the OP asked almost the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to pass the variable to style.php somehow, since it is not loaded until the page is rendered by the browser. So your stylesheet href would be `"style.php?gbvariable=<?php echo $gbvariable; ?>"` and you could then use `$_GET['gbvariable']` in stylesheet.php.

Comment: just copied that bit from his example. should be `<?= $gbvariable; ?>` or `<?php echo $gbvariable; ?>` obviously. I'll edit it.

Comment: That's (among other things) why I directed OP to the PHP manual :)

Answer (score 1):

I did:

```
echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/style.php?var1=$gbvariable\" type=\"text/css\" />";
```

and into style.php file just add

```
<?php $gbvariable=$_GET['var1']; ?>`
```

And it worked a treat. [Props to Chris P.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963868/including-a-global-variable-into-a-php-stylesheet/24218374#comment14314363_10963868), wouldn't have even thought of it.